# Trying to capitalize first character of a word with forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Why does the first block of code work (with for loop) and the second doesn't (with forEach)?

(I am trying to make all words start with an uppercase letter in a string)

1)

```
function capitalize(str){
  let wordList = str.split(" ");

  for (i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++){
    wordList[i] = wordList[i][0].toUpperCase() + wordList[i].substring(1);
  };

  return wordList.join(' ');
};

let str = "How are you doing today?";
console.log(capitalize(str));
```

2)

```
function capitalize(str){
  let wordList = str.split(" ");

  wordList.forEach(function(word){
    word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  })

  return wordList.join(' ');
};

let str = "How are you doing today?";
console.log(capitalize(str));
```

Comment: `word` is passed by value to the callback function of `forEach()`. You're not overwriting the element in the array.

Comment: Try `wordList = wordList.map(function(word){
    return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  })`; instead. Or `wordList.forEach(function(word, index, array){
    array[index] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  })` if you insist on using `forEach()` instead of `map()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `String.replace()` with a regular expression ([regex101](http://How%20are%20you%20doing%20today?)):

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  return str.replace(/\b./g, c => c.toUpperCase());
};

const str = "How are you doing today?";

const result = capitalize(str);

console.log(result);
```

Why doesn't assigning in the `Array.forEach()` work?

Since word is a string (a primitive like number or boolean), and primitives in JS are immutable (you can't change them, reassigning the variable has no effect. In addition, the values are store in the array, and you can change the array in a very ugly way (**Not recommended. Don't use!**), because arrays in JS are mutable (can be changed).

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  let wordList = str.split(" ");

  wordList.forEach(function(word, i) {
    wordList[i] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
  })

  return wordList.join(' ');
};

let str = "How are you doing today?";
console.log(capitalize(str));
```

Comment: Thanks. Mine is better :-P

Comment: This is the closest thing to look behind that JS had to offer `till ES2018. Very useful.

Comment: note the same advice applies to the working for loop example. don't modify the original array.. create a new one to store the results

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.map` instead of `.forEach` as map returns a new array with changed (mapped) values.

```
wordList = wordList.map((word) =>
    word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use your own forEach, update the code as below,
Here the callback for forEach takes 2nd argument the index, and you can store the modified value inside wordList and not in word.

```
function capitalize(str){
    let wordList = str.split(" ");

    //console.log(wordList);

    wordList.forEach(function(word, index){
        wordList[index] = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    })

    return wordList.join(' ');
  };

  let str = "How are you doing today?";
  console.log(capitalize(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :)
Basically, you forgot to update the initial array.

```js
function capitalize(str){
  let wordList = str.split(" ");
  wordList.forEach(function(word, ind){
    word = word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
    wordList[ind] = word;
  })

  return wordList.join(' ');
};

let str = "How are you doing today?";
console.log(capitalize(str));
```

Answer (score -1):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does nothing to modify the target array, you're simply throwing away the assignments. The function you're looking for is [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) which will transform each value and return a new array. In this case:

```js
function capitalize(s) {
  return s.split(' ').map(w => `${w[0].toUpperCase()}${w.substring(1)}`).join(' ')
}

console.log(capitalize('some words'))
```